# Want to make a custom table in action script3?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, actionscript, flex3, flex4

i want to make a table using action script 3.The description of the table is that table should have three parts 
one is header
second body
third footer.
Every part of the table mean header footer body also tables which can contain more than one row.
Please any one can give me idea about table.
Which container mean to use to accomplish this task.Any suggestion like this table.

thanks in advance!!!!

Comment: Are these requirements complete? Need you some interaction for that table (header sorting, row selection or highlighting etc.)?

Comment: @Constantiner i think thses are letter task. First i want to make a table which have three container mean header footer and body.My question is about which conatiner i will used. For my outer and inner tables and for rows and cells...

Answer (score 1):

The simple Datagrid component does not let you have a footer.
Here is a simple DataGrid Example http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=dpcontrols_6.html

Incase you are looking for a footer as well, check this out :
http://code.seanhess.net/?p=17
http://files.seanhess.net/demos/FooterDataGrid/Test.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`Grid` container](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/containers/Grid.html) which can do the same as `table` tag in HTML.

Answer (score 0):

You probably should use the DataGrid component. There's an example in the online help which should get you started.

There are also some third party components for rendering html tables in Flash, if you prefer that.